# how to show the html contents to the webview using android

Tags: html, android, android-webview

Following is my html content which i want to show in the webview using android sdk. It will displays only

> //Please

But when I put this HTML content into the browser then it shows differently.

```
<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework


help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school



// --><font color="#60c000" size="4"><strong>Please!</strong></font>
```

Please suggest how to resolve this problem

I have another problem that in HTML content there is a tag

```
<img src="http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif" border="0" />
```

in this images does not shows.

Comment: How your loading this html data into the webview?

Comment: here description contains my html code


web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadData(description, "text/html", "utf-8");

Answer (score 77, accepted):

1. Use web.loadDataWithBaseURL instead of web.loadData (And don't forget to escape strings where it's needed)
2. You need to add internet permission to download images and view them in your manifest file.

This example works for me:

```
public class SimpleMusicStream extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);        

        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String html = "<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework" +
                "help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school" +
                "// --><font color='#60c000' size='4'><strong>Please!</strong></font>" +
                "<img src='http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif'  />";


        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
    }

}
```

And don't forget to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: And don't forget to escape strings where it's needed - is there a utils class for this?

Comment: `wv.loadData(htmlString, mimeType, encoding);` would be better if you don't have base & history urls.

`loadData(htmlString, mimeType, encoding);` just parses the html content only.

Comment: web view says refuse to load " Refusing to load invalid URL"

Answer (score 10):

Either you can do it as above or put html file into the asset folder and the use it loke this to display it

```
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/FILENAME.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

for image display you can do it like

```
 String str= " img src=\"http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif\" alt=\"this is img\"ALIGN=\"right\"/>";
    wv.loadData(str, "text/html", "utf-8");
```