# how set text color of webview in android

Tags: android, webview

i am trying to change text color of webview with this code

```
String message ="<font color='white'>"+"<u>"+
"text in white"+ "<br>" +
"<font color='cyan'>"+"<font size='2'>"+
" text in blue color "+"</font>";
webview.loadData(message, "text/html", "utf8");
```

but i have some html pages. store in my sdcard then how can i change text color..

i use

```
webViewRead.loadUrl(url);
```

url is path of my file.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624171/how-to-show-the-html-contents-to-the-webview-using-android

Comment: but i want to display html pages not text..wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
in this method where should i put my path(file) plz dis-crib.

Comment: If you want to load html file then put the HTML file into the assets folder. Refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10844221/1263679

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to give the path of that file like this.

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + "/folder_name";

File directory = new File(extStorageDirectory);
File fileInDirectory = new File(directory,file_name.html);

//Read text from file
StringBuilder html_text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInDirectory));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        html_text.append(line);
        html_text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```

then use this html code for edit

```
String message ="<font color='white'>"+"<u>"+"text in white"+ "<br>" +"<font color='cyan'>"+"<font size='2'>"+" text in blue color "+"</font>"; 
 webview.loadData(message, "text/html", "utf8");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
htmlDetail = dbValues.getContent(3);
        tvDescription3.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        String finalHtml = "<html><head>"
                  + "<style type=\"text/css\">li{color: #00f} span {color: #000}"
                  + "</style></head>"
                  + "<body>"                          
                  + htmlDetail
                  + "</body></html>";

    tvDescription3.loadData(finalHtml, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

put your file path as

```
String htmlPath = "file:///mnt/sdcard/test/11.html"; 
String baseUrl = "file:///mnt/sdcard/test/"; 
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, message, "text/html", "utf-8", null); 
webView.loadUrl(htmlPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change a WebView’s background color there is a standard way:

```
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
```

In order to change a WebView’s text font color there is no standard way:
Either you change the font through the html code, or you do this:

```
htmlData="<font color='black'>" + htmlData + "</font>";
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```