# Add content in to the Webview?

Tags: android, webview

Is any way to add the Html contents in to the webview through the Main Xml file.

I have a one problem.I'm new in the android field,I load the contents from the assets file and normally the webview contents visible but when i going to swipe the page ,that contents not visible only containing black page ,after swipe next page visible...

so ,anyone give me the tips how to solve this problem.

advance in Thanks...

Comment: `but when i going to swipe the page` ?

Comment: No you cannot change the webview contents from the xml. Swiping part is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Check this.....
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/gettingstarted
[how to show the html contents to the webview using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624171/how-to-show-the-html-contents-to-the-webview-using-android)

Comment: I know that,how to add the content statically in webview through xml layout.i except dynamically add the content in webview...

Comment: You cant do it. Why are you trying to do it? Just post the real problem and we will help you.

Comment: how set the content to webview directly in xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link can help you: [Displaying Android asset files in a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320288/displaying-android-asset-files-in-a-webview)

However, you should give us more information. If you want to view an external URL, you will need to add permisions on the Android Manifest. If that is not your case and your content is local, maybe the problem is inside your Webpage.