# How to parse HTML to display it in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I get this `String` from API which should be a HTML:

`"&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Without Flavor &amp;amp; Size&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;With Gallery Images&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;With Tag&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;With User Review&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Inventory: In stock&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Visibility: Enable&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;With Regular Price&amp;nbsp; / Without Sale Price&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Without Role based pricing&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Without Upsells and Cross-sells Products&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;With one user review&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Stock Availability: In Stock&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Manage Stock: No&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"`

Which is translated in a TextView like this when I use `Html.fromHtml`:

[image: broken html in a textview]

My question is how to display this text like the web page (which should be an unorder list) in TextView.

I tried `Html.fromHtml`, but it doesn't work and tried many external libs with no success.

Comment: Use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView), I would highly suggest against trying to write your own HTML parser.

Comment: I tried it still shows the same. Did I need to add more meta-data to the text?

Comment: Did you [try it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3629454/1790644)?

Comment: I try this  `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", URLEncoder.encode(description,"UTF-8"),"text/html","UTF-8","");` but it shows it something like what i get from the API

Comment: The second field should get raw HTML, why are you URL encoding it?

Comment: Because I try the raw html but it shows it like the screen shot so I try to escape Strings